# perform filtering macro on an excel worksheet in a workbook, from another worksheet in a different workbook

Tags: vba, excel, filter, excel-2010

I have 2 work books, Book_1 and Book_2.

I have written a macro to perform filtering functions.

```
    Sub filter_5PKT_rows()

    Dim My_Range As Range
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim ViewMode As Long


    'Set filter range on ActiveSheet: A1 is the top left cell of the filter range
    'and the header of the first column, L is the last column in the filter range.
    'can also add the sheet name to the code like this

 Set My_Range = Range("A1:L" & LastRow(ActiveSheet))

 ' select my range

 My_Range.Parent.Select

 If ActiveWorkbook.ProtectStructure = True Or _
       My_Range.Parent.ProtectContents = True Then
        MsgBox "Sorry, not working when the workbook or worksheet is protected", _
               vbOKOnly, "Copy to new worksheet"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

'Firstly, remove the AutoFilter
    My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

   ' My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="=5PKT Men's"

   My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=Array("5PKT Men's", "5PKT Women's", "5PKT Short"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

   ' subline and cs(commercial sample) line have no connection to pocket setter
   ' therefore need to filter out these lines

   My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("Band 01", "Band 02", "Band 03", "Band 04", "Band 05", "Band 06", "Band 07", "Band 08", "Band 09", "Band 10", "Band 11", "Band 12", "Band 13", "Band 14", "Band 15", "Band 16", "Band 17", "Band 18", "Band 19", "Band 20"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

 ' DO NOT SORT ACCORDING TO ORDER QUANTITY.
 ' THIS IS BECAUSE THERE ARE INSTANCES,
 ' WHERE THE SAME STYLE NUMBER IS BROKEN INTO SEVERAL POS EACH HAVING VARYING ORDER QUANTITIES

'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
    My_Range.Parent.Select
    ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With

End Sub

Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

................................................................................

This code works and performs the filtering according to my desire.

Say i have rows in Book_1, worksheet_1,using the vba editor,

i insert a module for VBA project Book_1 and type the coding,

and run the macro,

then the filtering occurs.

............................................................................

**But: This code will not enable me to perform filtering in Book_1 worksheet_1,**

**if i place and execute the macro from Book_2 worksheet_1.**

**I want to perform the filtering macro in Book_A worksheet1, from Book_2 worksheet1.**

**How can this be done? How do i edit my coding?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
Sub filter_5PKT1_rows()




    Dim file_name  As String
    Dim sheet_name As String

   file_name = "C:\Users\Desktop\pocket setter excel\production_plan.xlsm"  'Change to whatever file i want
   sheet_name = "production_plan"   'Change to whatever sheet i want


' we set wb as a new work book sonce we have to open it

Dim wb As New Workbook

' To open and activate workbook, in this case production_plan
' it opens and activates the workbook production_plan and activates the worksheet production plan
' note: the work book has the name production_plan.xlsm and worksheet has the name production_plan

Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(file_name)

wb.Sheets(sheet_name).Activate

    Dim My_Range As Range
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim ViewMode As Long


    'Set filter range on ActiveSheet: A1 is the top left cell of the filter range
    'and the header of the first column, L is the last column in the filter range.
    'can also add the sheet name to the code like this

 Set My_Range = Range("A1:L" & LastRow(wb.ActiveSheet))

 ' select my range

 My_Range.Parent.Select

 If ActiveWorkbook.ProtectStructure = True Or _
       My_Range.Parent.ProtectContents = True Then
        MsgBox "Sorry, not working when the workbook or worksheet is protected", _
               vbOKOnly, "Copy to new worksheet"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    wb.ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

'Firstly, remove the AutoFilter
    My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

   ' My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="=5PKT Men's"

   My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=Array("5PKT Men's", "5PKT Women's", "5PKT Short"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

   ' subline and cs(commercial sample) line have no connection to pocket setter
   ' therefore need to filter out these lines

   My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("Band 01", "Band 02", "Band 03", "Band 04", "Band 05", "Band 06", "Band 07", "Band 08", "Band 09", "Band 10", "Band 11", "Band 12", "Band 13", "Band 14", "Band 15", "Band 16", "Band 17", "Band 18", "Band 19", "Band 20"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

 ' DO NOT SORT ACCORDING TO ORDER QUANTITY.
 ' THIS IS BECAUSE THERE ARE INSTANCES,
 ' WHERE THE SAME STYLE NUMBER IS BROKEN INTO SEVERAL POS EACH HAVING VARYING ORDER QUANTITIES

'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
    My_Range.Parent.Select
    ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With

End Sub

Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```